# Exporting colour image from GIMP turns grey

Tags: gimp, export

I have a gif image that I want to use as a background on a web site, but it's a bit too colourfull and when text is laid over the top of it, there's not enough contrast, so I want to knock it back a little.

I thought I could use a plain white layer in GIMP (v2.10.6) on top of my image and set that white layer to 50% opacity. On the screen, it looks about right, but when I try to export my image, parts of it just turn plain white, and other bits go grey. Same problem if I reverse this and set the original image to 50% opacity over a white background.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I've tried exporting as PNG, GIF, and JPG, but the result is the same for all three.

FYI, I get the same result if I try playing around with lightness and saturation settings instead of the white layer.

Here are some links to illustrate the problem:

- Original image https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iKLFFN39-4MK5iKRuvazVqfHox3c5RFP
- Screen shots of GIMP https://drive.google.com/open?id=10UR1Awqoo-OUJsic8xcaIxqujDRV6lyd
- Exported image https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dkVXDdWr7OD9RnUEolCevHrsktCeQrdz

How do I get the exported image to look like the image in GIMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original image is a GIF, so when you load the image in Gimp it handles it as a color-indexed image (as indicated in the title bar).

Make your image full-RGB (Image>Mode>RGB) before working on it.